# while i was making a Calculator program through java i dont understand why use the code " Calculator.nextDouble(); " ?

Tags: java

So i made this addition calulating program. These are the following codes i used:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class apples {
    public static void main(String args []){
        Scanner Calculator = new Scanner (System.in) ;

        double fnum, snum, answer;

        System.out.println("Enter first num: ");
        fnum = Calculator.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second num: ");
        snum = Calculator.nextDouble();
        answer = fnum + snum;
       System.out.println(answer);


    }
}
```

So i dont understand why do i have to use this code to make it work 
 " Calculator.nextDouble(); "

Comment: waits for a value to be inputted

Comment: What other code would you like to use? N.B. in Java variables are **always** in `camelCase`; and classes in `PascalCase` - your code has it backwards. Please ensure that you **always** stick to Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to somehow fetch a number from the user, and this method call will do so.

P.S. Look up the naming conventions in Java, classes are always given Pascal-case names and variables are always given Camel-case names.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner gets data from console(for example) method nexDouble() return data from console , but casted to double type. Os you can work with numbers (double numbers).This class has also methods nexInt() , and others, you can check it in documentation.
When you call this method  Calculator.nextDouble();  you will get data from console , that user will input , so it class scan data from soncole

Comment: So you create an object Calculator.type Scanner , and you can gets data from console